# Haskell - wrapping and unwrapping newtype wrappers - is there an easier way?

Tags: haskell, monoids

I'm writing a function `pad` that takes a list and pads it until it is a certain size. I tried 2 implementations:

```
pad :: Monoid a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
pad len list = replicate (len - length list) mempty ++ list
```

and

```
pad :: Int -> a ->  [a] -> [a]
pad len value list = replicate (len - length list) value ++ list
```

The first one seems to be a logical usage of `Monoid` but calling it with lists of integers (or anything that is a `Monoid` in multiple ways) is a pain:

```
(fmap getSum) <$> pad 8 <$> (fmap Sum) <$> [1,2,3]
```

I don't really mind the extra typing, but it doesn't even seem to convey the meaning very well. How would you implement this function?

Comment: I would use `pad :: Int -> a ->  [a] -> [a]`. Sometimes, one wants to pad with a different value.

Comment: Exercise for the curious. Consider `data Paddy a = [a] :...: a` and equip `Paddy` with a zipping `Applicative` structure which pairs up the values left of `:...:` but deals with length mismatch by padding the shorter list with the value given after the `:...:`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd probably use your second example, to be honest. Adding a `Monoid` constraint just to use `mempty` as a "default value" is overkill. It also sends the wrong message to users of this function, who may be confused about what you need `mappend` for when you really don't. They would also have to make a `newtype` and a `Monoid` instance if they wanted to pad with a different value.

Instead, consider changing the order of the arguments so that the value comes first. Then you can just apply it partially whenever you need to pad a lot of lists with the same value. You can also recover the first version with `pad mempty` if you need it.

Comment: I like the partial application suggestion. I think I'll use that.